# How to add a WmAsfReader Filter into the directshow filtergraph using c#? Using the qasf.dll right?

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net, wmv

I create a Directshow Filtergraph using c#,but i dont know how to add a 
WmAsfReader Filter which can decode the video file into the filtergraph.
Can anybody help,thanks!

The code below is what i have done.

```
/*MediaUriPlayer*/
protected virtual void OpenSource()
    {
        FrameCount = 0;
        /* Make sure we clean up any remaining mess */
        FreeResources();
        /* make sure source is not null */
        if (m_sourceUri == null)
            return;

        string fileSource = m_sourceUri.OriginalString;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileSource))
            return;

        try
        {
            /* Creates the GraphBuilder COM object */
            m_graph = new FilterGraphNoThread() as IGraphBuilder;

            if (m_graph == null)
                throw new Exception("Could not create a graph");


            /* Add our prefered audio renderer */
            InsertAudioRenderer(AudioRenderer);

            var filterGraph = m_graph as IFilterGraph2;

            if (filterGraph == null)
                throw new Exception("Could not QueryInterface for the IFilterGraph2");

            IBaseFilter renderer = CreateVideoMixingRenderer9(m_graph, 1);                                

            IBaseFilter sourceFilter;

            /* Have DirectShow find the correct source filter for the Uri */
            var hr = filterGraph.AddSourceFilter(fileSource, fileSource, out sourceFilter);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            /* We will want to enum all the pins on the source filter */
            IEnumPins pinEnum;

            hr = sourceFilter.EnumPins(out pinEnum);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

            IntPtr fetched = IntPtr.Zero;
            IPin[] pins = { null };

            /* Counter for how many pins successfully rendered */
            int pinsRendered = 0;                

            /* Loop over each pin of the source filter */
            while (pinEnum.Next(pins.Length, pins, fetched) == 0)
            {
                if (filterGraph.RenderEx(pins[0],
                                         AMRenderExFlags.RenderToExistingRenderers,
                                         IntPtr.Zero) >= 0)
                pinsRendered++;

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pins[0]);
            }

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pinEnum);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sourceFilter);

            if (pinsRendered == 0)
                throw new Exception("Could not render any streams from the source Uri");

            /* Configure the graph in the base class */
            SetupFilterGraph(m_graph);

            HasVideo = true;
            /* Sets the NaturalVideoWidth/Height */
            //SetNativePixelSizes(renderer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            /* This exection will happen usually if the media does
             * not exist or could not open due to not having the
             * proper filters installed */
            FreeResources();

            /* Fire our failed event */
            InvokeMediaFailed(new MediaFailedEventArgs(ex.Message, ex));
        }

        InvokeMediaOpened();
    }
```

now the Directshow Filtergraph does not have sourcefilter,i want to add a WmAsfReader as a sourcefilter,but i dont know how to add!

Comment: Create an instance and do `AddFilter` instead of `AddSourceFilter` in your code.

Comment: How to create an instance? Which dll do I need?Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

> ...now the Directshow Filtergraph does not have sourcefilter,i want to add a WmAsfReader as a sourcefilter,but i dont know how to add!

With no reference that the code is in good standing overall, a [code snippet](https://github.com/babgvant/EVRPlay/blob/3288d2f45e0592d9dbae59ec955120456401a1f7/MainForm.cs#L1397) from it answers your question:

```
  hr = graphBuilder.AddSourceFilter(filename, "Source", out sourceFilter);
  if (hr < 0)
  {
    //if it doesn't work before failing try to load it with the WMV reader
    sourceFilter = (IBaseFilter)new WMAsfReader();
    hr = graphBuilder.AddFilter(sourceFilter, "WM/ASF Reader");
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
```

Comment: `IBaseFilter baseWrapperFilter = (IBaseFilter)new DMOWrapperFilter();
var dmoWrapperFilter = (IDMOWrapperFilter)baseWrapperFilter;
int hr = dmoWrapperFilter.Init(new Guid("{82d353df-90bd-4382-8bc2-3f6192b76e34}"), DMOCategory.VideoDecoder);
Console.WriteLine(hr);
return (IBaseFilter)dmoWrapperFilter;`

Comment: I tyied ur code,but the wmv file  didn't play.The code above is how i add a WmDecod Fliter.Is that wrong?